# $f(x)=(x^2,x^3)$ not an immersion but $Df$ one-to-one?

Tags: real-analysis, differential-geometry

Let $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R^2$ with $f(x)=(x^2,x^3)$. Then $f$ is not an immersion since $rank Df\neq1$ for $x=0$.

Our lecturer told us that this is equivalent that $Df$ is one-to-one. What is meant by that? Clearly $Df(x)=Df(y)\iff x=y$ so what is wrong?

Comment: "Clearly $Df(x) = Df(y) \iff x = y$" Could you explain why you think this is true?

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese we have $Df(x)=(2x,3x^2)=Df(y)$ and from the first line we get $x=y$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By definition, a function $f:\mathbb{R}^{m}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{n}$ is an immersion if and only if, for every $x\in\mathbb{R}^{m}$ the differential $Df(x)$ is an injective linear transformation. This is completely different than saying that the function $Df$ is injective. In you case for $x=0\in\mathbb{R}^{1}$ we have $Df(0)$ the zero transformation between $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{R}^{2}$, so $f$ is not an immersion.